# M[i,j]=randint(2,99): TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from numpy import *
from random import *
M=([[int]*20]*20)
def saisie():
    N=int(input("Saisir l'ordre de la matrice "))
    while not 4<N<20:
         N=int(input("Saisir l'ordre de la matrice "))
    return(N)
N=saisie()
def matrice(N):
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            M[i,j]=randint(2,99)
    return(M)
x=matrice(N)
```

I'm getting (M[i,j]=randint(2,99): TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple ) however the list indices are integers, what did i do wrong?

Comment: If you're using `numpy`, why not **use** it? You can specify a random integer and a shape like so: `np.random.randint(2,99, size=(20,20))`

Comment: "However the list indices are integers" well - `i` and `j` are, but the combination `i, j` is a tuple. That only works with a Numpy array, not with a native Python list. As an aside, `int` means **the integer type itself, not** a newly created integer.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign it to a list of lists like this.

```
M[i][j] = randint(2,99)
```

Comment: My teacher told me i can't do this for whatever reason, and i'm preparing for an exam, any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like this:

```
M[i][j]=randint(2,99)
```

Comment: It worked for now, however my list comes out like this: 
31 71 10 68 73 

31 71 10 68 73 

31 71 10 68 73 

31 71 10 68 73 

31 71 10 68 73
see the each 5 numbers it repeats, i would like completely different values every 5 numbers

Comment: "however my list comes out like this: " Okay, and **what is wrong with** that result?

Comment: i would like completely different values every 5 numbers

Comment: "the each 5 numbers it repeats" That has a completely different cause. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**; posts here are **not** to make your code work, but to **answer one, specific, clear question**.

Comment: @KakyoinJoestar it's because you're copying a pointer with the outer `*`. Take a look at my answer for a more detailed example and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

For numpy arrays this might work, `M` is just a standard python list, that does not allow multi indexing.

`M[i][j]= randint(2,99)`  should work

Better use `M = np.random.randint(2,99, size=(20,20))` just one line of code and no need for loops.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things here. One you can use numpy for this:

```
np.random.randint(2,99, size=(20,20))
```

Regardless, the way you initialize `M` is going to come back to haunt you.
`M=([[int]*20]*20)`. Let me give you an example:

```py
In [32]: M=([[0]*5]*5)

In [33]: M
Out[33]:
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

In [34]: M[0][0] = 5

In [35]: M
Out[35]:
[[5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [5, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Notice that when you do that syntax and try to change a single element, you're actually changing all the elements across the column. Why? Because that outer `*` is copying the pointer of the list. Instead you can use list comprehension for this.

```py
In [44]: M=[[0]*5 for _ in range(5)]

In [45]: M
Out[45]:
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

In [46]: M[0][0] = 5

In [47]: M
Out[47]:
[[5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Notice that I'm not using the outer `*` and now when I change a single element within the list of lists, only one element is changed.